# Override View Output for Shopping Cart

Tags: theming

i am theming a template and currently working shopping cart section. The commerce module provides a view 'Shopping cart block' out of box. I am trying utilize this view, however, i am unable to rewrite the html code from the UI the way i need. So, i am looking to do the same in code using hooks.

```
function theme_views_pre_render(&$view){
    var_dump('got in pre view');
}
```

Is this the proper hook? Where is the output markup stored for views? Is there a render array of view output available that i could manipulate before its rendered? Thank you

Comment: That's the right hook, but you need to implement it in a custom module; it's not a theme or alter hook so it won't work inside a theme. You can use template files though, and preprocess those; you can find a list of all template files that will work for the view under Advanced -> Theme:Information

Comment: Thank You Clive. The template file was solution(kind of still is), but the challenge is to get the necessary values - total amount and total items of shopping cart all part of the view. Those values seem missing in the '$variable' array in preprocess/processor functions and template file. There is already rendered markup but i don't want parse it for those values. Is making another query to db the only solution to get those values in preprocess function?

Comment: one more thing...when you say the hook - theme_views_pre_render is not working under theme. My debugger executes this hook within template.tpl.php...that seems to be working for me. would you, please, clarify when you say not working?..i am little confused. this D7. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was:
verride the 'shopping cart block' view with custom template
    block--cart-blockNameInClonedView.tpl.php(referece themer-info for
    exact name).

Populate the 'vars' array with total number of items and total amount of a shopping cart in block preprocessor function as following:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook){
    if ($vars['block']->region == 'cart_in_header') {
            if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($vars['user']->uid)) {
                $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
                $bazar_cart = array();
                $bazar_cart['total-qty'] = commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());
                $price_raw= commerce_line_items_total($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types())['amount'];
                $bazar_cart['total-price'] = substr($price_raw,0,-2).'.'.substr($price_raw,-2);

                $vars['bazar_cart'] = $bazar_cart;
            }
      }
}
```

In custom block template file, the variable '$bazar_cart' is available to plug the values(total items and total amount of cart) as you wish in the html structure